# Read Meteor Session on a different page

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I want to display a "Welcome back" message on the home page after the user performs a successful signIn. However, after I make a redirect with `Router.go('home');`, I can't read the Session within my `Template.home.rendered = function()`.
Here is my code:

Login logic:

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    showError();
                } else {
                    Session.set('signInSuccess', true);
                    Router.go('home');
                }
            });

Template.home.rendered = function() {

    console.log(Session.get('signInSuccess'));
    if (Session.get('signInSuccess') == true) {
        showWelcomeMessage();
        Session.set('signInSuccess', null);
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because `Template.home.rendered` is executed exactly once when your template is first inserted in the DOM (it may get executed again if the template is destroyed and reinserted, via the routing mechanism).

See rendered behavior here : http://docs.meteor.com/#template_rendered

Try wrapping your verification code inside an autorun :

```
Template.home.rendered=function(){
  // setup a reactive computation to watch for Session variable modification
  this.autorun(functon(){
    // using Session.equals is better than checking against Session.get
    // see http://docs.meteor.com/#session_equals
    if(Session.equals("signInSuccess",true)){
      showWelcomeMessage();
      Session.set("signInSuccess",false);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, the page is rendered more than once, so I see the welcome message for a very short time, is it possible to solve this?

Comment: Sure, please edit your question and post more code so I can better understand how you proceed : your routing code, the showWelcomeMessage,  etc...

Comment: Changed `template.rendered` to `template.created` and it works now! Thanks!